# How to add downloaded content to an IOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, plist

I´m trying to make an iPhone-app where the users can buy and download new content (sound  files). 
I´ve used the API from Urban Airship to set up the "in-app store", so the buying and downloading the new files part is covered and seems to work as it should - but I´m having a hard time figuring out how to add the new content to my app so the user can access it..

The app comes with 3 sound files to start with, and I´m using a Plist to display and play these files - displayed in a tableview based on my plist.
In my simple mind I´m thinking that I need to add the new content to my existing plist, or I should get my tableview to display content from multiple plists so every new download could contain a plist with info about the downloaded files..

This is my first time trying to make an app, and I am completely lost!
How do I add downloaded content to my app? Should i do something else instead of the plist?

Comment: Just update the info in the plist when the download is done. Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your initial plist from the app bundle, where it isn't writeable, to your app's Documents directory, where you can write and append info to the plist as necessary.  Then just populate your table from that one plist.